# Silently removing key from a python dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a python dict and I'd like to silently remove either `None` and `''` keys from my dictionary so I came up with something like this:

```
try:
    del my_dict[None]
except KeyError:
    pass

try:
    del my_dict['']
except KeyError:
   pass
```

As you see, it is less readable and it causes me to write duplicate code. So I want to know if there is a method in python to remove any key from a dict without throwing a key error?

Comment: Aren't you mixing *values* and *keys* here?

Comment: I am confused, why would a key not appear in `dict.keys()`?

Answer (score 155, accepted):

You can do this:

```
d.pop("", None)
d.pop(None, None)
```

Pops dictionary with a default value that you ignore.

Comment: Be careful not to write d.pop(None) - As this will raise a KeyError as no default value was provided

Comment: how would I remove keys with a `None` value?

Comment: knowbody: You can do exactly as this answer above said:
d.pop(None, None)

Comment: Ran into the gotcha mentioned by andy boot. Just for clarity, here's what the docs say: `If default is not given and key is not in the dictionary, a KeyError is raised.`

Answer (score 15):

You could use the `dict.pop` method and ignore the result:

```
for key in [None, '']:
    d.pop(key, None)
```

Answer (score 3):

The following will delete the keys, if they are present, and it won't throw an error:

```
for d in [None, '']:
    if d in my_dict:
        del my_dict[d]
```

Comment: @ozgurv Dictionary lookup is not O(n), it is O(1)

Comment: @ozgurv: checking whether a key is in a dict is O(1), as is deleting a key from a dict. It *does* however cause you to do two lookups rather than one.

Comment: @ozgurv no, it's not. Check out the Python docs on [time complexity](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) for data structures. You aren't looking for keys that end up in the amortized case there either.

Comment: Thank you I was not aware of that. I thought sth like: if d in my_sexy_dict.keys(). Because .keys() returns a list and I consider as searching an element in a list.

Comment: @ozgurv `my_sexy_dict.keys()` is not O(1), because it generates a list first (or in Python a "view"). `k in my_sexy_dict` is O(1)

Comment: @ozgurv In Python 3 `dict.keys` no longer returns a list so they are practically the same, as they should be.

Comment: @jamylak you're definitely right, I never understood why it returns a list instead of a set.

Comment: I think it returns a list so that if you iterate over `keys()` and `values()` you get the key-value pairs. (I know, why would you do this intead of using `items()`? I don't know.)  If you want a set of the keys in dict `dd`, you can just use `set(dd)` - the default iterator over a dict is to iterate over its keys.

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
d = dict((k, v) for k,v in d.items() if k is not None and k != '')
```

or to remove all empty-like keys

```
d = dict((k, v) for k,v in d.items() if k )
```

Comment: No need for `[`, `]`. You are creating an unnecessary intermediary list comprehension. If you remove them, the more efficient generator will be used.