# Explicit passing named (keyword) arguments when used with formal (positional), *args and **kwargs

Tags: python, arguments

I have following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import os

from pprint import pprint as pp

def test_var_args(farg, default=1, *args, **kwargs):
    print "type of args is", type(args)
    print "type of args is", type(kwargs)

    print "formal arg:", farg
    print "default arg:", default

    for arg in args:
        print "another arg:", arg

    for key in kwargs:
        print "another keyword arg: %s: %s" % (key, kwargs[key])

    print "last argument from args:", args[-1]


test_var_args(1, "two", 3, 4, myarg2="two", myarg3=3)
```

Above code outputs:

```
type of args is <type 'tuple'>
type of args is <type 'dict'>
formal arg: 1
default arg: two
another arg: 3
another arg: 4
another keyword arg: myarg2: two
another keyword arg: myarg3: 3
last argument from args: 4
```

As you can see as a default argument is passed "two". But I do not want to assign to the default variable anything unless I say it explicitly. In other words, I want that aforementioned command returns this:

```
type of args is <type 'tuple'>
type of args is <type 'dict'>
formal arg: 1
default arg: 1
another arg: two
another arg: 3
another arg: 4
another keyword arg: myarg2: two
another keyword arg: myarg3: 3
last argument from args: 4
```

Changing the default variable should be done explicitly, e.g. using something like this (following command gives compilation error, it was just my attempt)
`test_var_args(1, default="two", 3, 4, myarg2="two", myarg3=3)`:

```
type of args is <type 'tuple'>
type of args is <type 'dict'>
formal arg: 1
default arg: two
another arg: 3
another arg: 4
another keyword arg: myarg2: two
another keyword arg: myarg3: 3
last argument from args: 4
```

I have tried following but it also returns an compilation error:
`test_var_args(1,, 3, 4, myarg2="two", myarg3=3)`

Is this possible?

Comment: What is wrong with treating `default` as an optional `kwarg`, and including in your method the line `default = kwargs.get('default', 1)`?

Comment: Probably nothing, can you please post working code snippet in answer. I've tried to modify my code according your suggestion and added this `default = kwargs.get('default', 1)` as my first line in subroutine but it return me compilation error and/or takes 3 as a default value when called following way `test_var_args(1, 3, 4, myarg2="two", myarg3=3, default="default")`

Comment: @WakanTanka Have a look at my answer, it contains a sample :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think that's possible.

As Sam pointed out, you could achieve the same behaviour by taking the value out of the kwargs. If your logic *depends* on kwargs **not** containing the "default" argument, you can just remove it from the kwargs dictionary using the `pop` method (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11358411/silently-remove-key-from-a-python-dict)). The following code behaves like you want it:

```
import sys
import os

from pprint import pprint as pp

def test_var_args(farg, *args, **kwargs):
    print "type of args is", type(args)
    print "type of args is", type(kwargs)

    print "formal arg:", farg
    print 'default', kwargs.pop('default', 1)

    for arg in args:
        print "another arg:", arg

    for key in kwargs:
        print "another keyword arg: %s: %s" % (key, kwargs[key])

    print "last argument from args:", args[-1]

# Sample call
test_var_args(1, 3, 4, default="two", myarg2="two", myarg3=3)
```

which works similar to how you wanted in your question